# How to remove spaces between words and replace with single underscore using only 'REPLACE','INSTR' OR 'SUBSTR' oracle function

Tags: oracle

I want to replace spaces between words with a single underscore using  'REPLACE','INSTR' OR 'SUBSTR' oracle functions.

```
example:

    "my name is            xyz" =>  "my_name_is_xyz"
    "test    sdf"               =>  "test_sdf"
```

is it possible to get above output with 'REPLACE','INSTR' OR 'SUBSTR' .

Note: I dont want to use replace_regex

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) already asked here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265623

Comment: reason i posted here because i had explained many times there that i want output using replace,instr, or substr function but unfortunately nobody got my point

Answer (score 1):

Nested replaces might help.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'my name is            xyz' from dual union all
  3     select 'test    sdf'               from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6    replace(replace(replace(replace(col, ' ', '# '), ' #'), '#'), ' ', '_') result
  7  from test;

COL                       RESULT
------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
my name is            xyz my_name_is_xyz
test    sdf               test_sdf

SQL>
```

Comment: What happens if the input has a `#` in it, as part of the original data?

Comment: Then some other character should be used, @Tim. How to know which one, exactly? I don't know. Maybe `š` would help, if it doesn't exist in OPs character set. Or Greek capital letter theta `ϴ`. Question was: how to replace multiple spaces with underscore. That *ugly* 4 x `replace` is one option. I prefer regexp for that, but - it was said that it should be avoided.

Comment: This is probably the best answer that can be given, just pointing out in production, it might not be suitable for everyone who reads it, that is all.

Comment: I'm not saying that your comment was *wrong*, @Tim. Quite a few questions here are related to "interviews", where people were asked *how* to do something without using the obvious. Or, maybe they use Oracle 7.1 that doesn't support regular expressions. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The *best* option here probably is to use `REGEXP_REPLACE`, so I will suggest it:

```
SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '\s+', '_') AS col_underscore
FROM yourTable;
```

Regular expressions fit well here, because you have an unknown amount of whitespace.

Comment: Are you certain that none of your data would have the `#` character in it?